# serialise and deserialise object from Silverlight and Windows exe

Tags: .net, xml, silverlight

Ok, so I have a front-end Silverlight GUI and a backend Windows service running on the server. The front end puts requests in a SQL Server DB and the service deals with them. The bulk of the request is an object that I would like the Silverlight to serialise to an XML string and put in the DB. The Windows service needs to deserilise it.

So I need a class that can be referenced by both Silverlight and a normal C# Windows program and can be at least serialised to a string by Silverlight and deserialised from a string by a Windows service.

The object itself does not have anything specific to Silverlight but it has to be in a Silverlight dll for the front end to use it. But that means I have to use Silverlight methods to deserialise it and they don't work when called from the service.

The only thing I can do is write a Serialise method in the class, using Silverlight, and a Deserialise method in the Windows Service, using normal .Net.

Is there a better way?

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a [WCF RIA service project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).  This allows you to share a single code base, which Visual Studio compiles to separate Silverlight and .Net assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- write the code as a *portable class library*, selecting the frameworks you need; this gives you a single dll that can be used by multiple frameworks, but (obviously) limits you to the shared subset (intersection) of functionality available by the frameworks you select
- compile the same DTO code *separately* on multiple frameworks; most standard DTO code will compile fine for Silverlight and Windows targets - since they are mainly jut adding `XmlSerializer` attributes etc - nothing very target-specific. `XmlSerializer` exists for both

Note that xml works fine between languages, operating-systems, hardware, etc - getting it working between Silverlight and Windows is fairly mundane.